# How do I use the react-admin's SelectArrayInput element to send data to the server as an array of objects i.e. { clients: [id: 1, id: 2]}?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

In react-admin I have the following `ReferenceArrayInput` -> `SelectArrayInput` component as following:

```
<Create {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>

        <ReferenceArrayInput source="clients" reference="client">
            <SelectArrayInput optionText="clientName" />
        </ReferenceArrayInput>

    </SimpleForm>
</Create>
```

It works, it receives the data from the `client` source and id displays the options with the `clientName` label.

However, when the form is submitted it sends to the server the following request body:

```
{
   "clients": [1,2,3]
{
```

I would like to send it as:

```
{
   "clients": [
     {"id": 1},
     {"id": 2},
     {"id": 3}
   ]
}
```

Is is possible, by setting some certain option or shall I use a different component?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options for this:

- Transform the data in your dataProvider
- Pass a transform function to the `transform` prop of your `Create` or `Edit` component.

  ```
  export const UserCreate = (props) => {
      const transform = (data) => ({
          ...data,
          clients: data.clients.map((id) => ({ id })),
      });

      return (
          <Create {...props} transform={transform}>
              // Your inputs
          </Create>
      );
  };
  ```

Comment: Thansk Gildas, very kind!